# Deprecated node in MULE 3.6.4, 3.5.0 and 3.7.2?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I well know JDBC was deprecated in MULE 3.5.0 & HTTP connector was deprecated from MULE 3.6.4.

But i want known, is it any other nodes are involved in this deprecated list?

As well as i want the deprecated node's list for MULE 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mule release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-esb) for each version.

For example, the [3.7.0 release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-esb-3.7.0-release-notes#deprecated-in-this-release) mentions the following deprecations:

> MULE-8260 As ASM 3.3.1 is not fully compliant with Java 8, the class
>   in the packages org.mule.util.scan and org.mule.util.scan.annotations
>   have been deprecated, however you can use them under Java 7.
>
> MULE-7588      Lifecycle has been fixed:
>   - TransientRegistry is deprecated and no longer used by the runtime. SpringRegistry is now the only registry the runtime uses by default.
>   AbstractMuleContextTestCase uses the new SimpleRegistry instead.
>   - addRegistry() and removeRegistry() methods from the MuleContext have been deprecated. Manually added registries cannot participate of
>   dependency injection
>   - The org.mule.api.registry.Registry.registerObject(key, Object, metadata) method has been deprecated. The metadata is no longer used.
>   - RegistryBroker and RegistryBrokerLifecycleManager classes have been deprecated
>   - SimpleRegistryBootstrap is deprecated and is no longer used by the runtime. SpringRegistryBootstrap is used instead
>   - PreInjectProcessor, InjectProcessor, ObjectProcessor and all their implementation have been deprecated and are no longer used by the
>   runtime. Use a Spring BeanPostProcessor instead
>
> MULE-8411 @deprecated As of 3.7.0, use {@link#toXMLStreamReader(javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory, org.mule.api.MuleEvent, Object)} instead.
>
> MULE-8469 NoActionTransformer class inside TCK test folder
>
> MULE-7742 class AsyncMessageProcessorWorker